# Как убрать alt для миниатюры, оставив его для основного изображения

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

Пытаюсь сделать слайдшоу с текстовым описанием каждой фотографии.
Но получаю текст либо и в основном изображении, и в миниатюре одновременно.
Либо текст не отображается вообще.

Подскажите, как убрать его из превьюшки, но оставить в большом изображении?

Спасибо!

Описание alt не отображется вообще, если я его добавляю к слайдам в блоке container.

Или alt отображается дважды, если я пытаюсь его добавить к превью.

Вот код:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */

.container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* Container for image text */

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Six columns side by side */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}


/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://baseflat.ru/1KKV-final.jpg" style="width:100%;"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="1ккв, ул.Хорошая, д.17. Аренда 25 000 руб/мес, КУ включены. Отличное состояние, вся бытовая техника. Залог. Для русской семьи, можно с детьми"> </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Описание alt отображается дважды, когда я пробую сделать так:

Вот код:

Comment: *К слову, `dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");` — всю эту строчку целиком можно заменить на `dots[i].classList.remove('active');`

Comment: А почему бы вам в начале скрипта не объявить переменные `slides, dots, captionText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не хочется отображать alt на картинках... можно везде подменить alt на `data-alt` (вместо alt может быть любое другое слово). А в скрипте можно получить записанное внутри `data-` через запись вида `element.dataset.alt`. В скрипте изменена только последняя строчка:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].dataset.alt;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */

.container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* Container for image text */

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Six columns side by side */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}


/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img src="https://baseflat.ru/1KKV-final.jpg" style="width:100%;"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"> </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" data-alt="1ккв, ул.Хорошая, д.17. Аренда 25 000 руб/мес, КУ включены. Отличное состояние, вся бытовая техника. Залог. Для русской семьи, можно с детьми"> </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" data-alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" data-alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" data-alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" data-alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" data-alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Комментарии к вашему коду и немного другой вариант:

• У вас же и так задан класс `demo` для картинок. Задолбаетесь для каждой отдельно добавлять `style="width: 100%"` в HTML. Легче это прямо в CSS и прописать, `.demo {width: 100%};` Та же история и для `.mySlides img {width: 100%;}`

• Также, легко можно запутаться в этих onclick и их аргументах, если кода становится чуть больше. (как минимум) из-за этого уже стоит вместо этого записать клик прямо в скрипте, и дальше редактировать HTML как угодно, зная что скрипт всё равно сработает. (ищите статьи про **addEventListener vs onclick**)

• Вместо `<div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>` для каждого элемента, можно сразу в скрипте записать всю нумерацию - опять же, меньше заморочек в случае редактирования картинок.

• Если внутри элемента нужно добавить лишь текст, без HTML-кода, то принято использовать `innerText` вместо `innerHTML`. Первый просто вставляет все символы как текст, не разбирая... а второй лишний раз делает проверку на наличие HTML, чтобы выполнить его как код. Хоть при таких небольших текстах это особо и не заметно.

И...код:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/1urkwexh/)

```js
(function(){

let current = 0; /*Переменная для сохранения номера открытого слайда */
let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
let demo = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
let numbertext = document.getElementsByClassName("numbertext");
for( let i = 0; i < demo.length; i++ ){
  /*Сразу прописываем нумерацию слайдов*/
  numbertext[i].innerText = (i+1) + ' / ' + demo.length;
  
  /*На каждую картинку вешаем событие click...*/
  demo[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    /*Всё равно картинок и слайдов одинаковое кол-во, так?
    Значит можно вместо двух циклов использовать один*/
    for( let u = 0; u < demo.length; u++ ){
      demo[u].classList.remove('active');
      slides[u].style.display = 'none';
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
    slides[i].style.display = 'block';    
    captionText.innerText = this.dataset.alt;
    
    current = i; /* После клика каждый раз current получает новый номер кликнутой кнопки */
  });
}

document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener('click', function(){
  /* Это дело называется "тернарный оператор". При клике проверям - current равен 0 ?
  Если да - то ему некуда уменьшаться, станет = demo.length - 1
  А если нет, уменьшится на единицу, current--; */
  (current == 0) ? (current = demo.length - 1) : (current--);
  for( let u = 0; u < demo.length; u++ ){
    demo[u].classList.remove('active');
    slides[u].style.display = 'none';
  }
  captionText.innerText = demo[current].dataset.alt;
  demo[current].classList.add('active');
  slides[current].style.display = 'block';
});
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener('click', function(){
  ( current == (demo.length-1) ) ? (current = 0) : (current++);
  /*Оба записал так, чтобы было "перед глазами", что происходит...
  их можно записать в одной функции и вызвать её и тут, и там*/
  for( let u = 0; u < demo.length; u++ ){
    demo[u].classList.remove('active');
    slides[u].style.display = 'none';
  }
  captionText.innerText = demo[current].dataset.alt;
  demo[current].classList.add('active');
  slides[current].style.display = 'block';
});

})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.demo {width: 100%;}
.mySlides img {width: 100%;}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */

.container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* Container for image text */

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Six columns side by side */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}


/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <img src="https://baseflat.ru/1KKV-final.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"></div>
    <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg"> </div>
  <a id="prev" class="prev">❮</a>
  <a id="next" class="next">❯</a>
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_woods.jpg" data-alt="1ккв, ул.Хорошая, д.17. Аренда 25 000 руб/мес, КУ включены. Отличное состояние, вся бытовая техника. Залог. Для русской семьи, можно с детьми"> </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" data-alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains.jpg" data-alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights.jpg" data-alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature.jpg" data-alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow.jpg"data-alt="Snowy Mountains">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.s. если в нем что-то осталось непонятным, здесь такие переключения описаны подробнее... [JavaScript переключаемые вкладки - табы (и немного CSS)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-css/982073#982073)

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!